# Having issue with "identifier not found"

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ I'm getting "process_teleport_menu" identifier not found" error, I know in C, everything must be declared before being used.
this is piece of code:

```
if (bDown)
        {
            menu_beep();
            activeLineIndexPlayer2++;
            if (activeLineIndexPlayer2 == lineCount)
                activeLineIndexPlayer2 = 0;
            waitTime = 150;
        }else
        if (bRight)
        {                                  
            menu_beep();                     
            if (activeLineIndexPlayer2 = process_teleport_menu())  //Error
                activeLineIndexPlayer2 = 0;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int teleportActiveLineIndex = 0;

bool process_teleport_menu()
{
    const float lineWidth = 250.0;
    const int lineCount = 17;
```

Is there another way?

Comment: What is the *entire* error message?  If you're having trouble understanding the message, you're probably not in a position to summarize it.

Comment: Yes, there is another way. Start learning the language from scratch. In fact, based on this question, you should probably do the same with C (even though you claim to know it).

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `process_teleport_menu()` function before it's declared. You can declare the function before defining it, to indicate its existence before it's used: place `bool process_teleport_menu();` before the function containing the troublesome code, and that should work unless it's not your entire problem.

However, this question would have been answered by most C++ tutorials, so please go read one before asking another basic question.

Comment: Thanks, I started learning C++ 2 days ago, I just got bored by a tutorials and tried something new.